# Can't centre elements horizontally (image and text)

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have any idea of how to have the image and the text to be horizontal with each other but are centred within the green section within the example?  I need the image to be on the left and for the text to be on the right. I'm happy with the way it displays in mobile and tablet view, however, I just need to allow the content of the image and text to be displayed 50% (centred) within the green section even when the height of the green section is adjusting.

I think the main issue I'm having is that I have a min-height set for the green section, therefore it adjusts according to the size of the screen the user has.

The text appears very small when I adjust the height of the window to this size. It appears higher up in the green section, rather than in the middle:

[image]

```css
#expertise-section {
  background-color: #bce4b8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 0;
  min-height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
} /* Adjusts section sizing, padding and text alignment */



/*------------------------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
------------------------------------------------*/

#expertise-section h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Lobster Two", cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -2%;
} /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-title {
  margin-top: 0;
} /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

.expertise-section-title:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

.expertise-section-title span {
  background: #bce4b8;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

.expertise-section-content {
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-right: 14%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.expertise-section-content img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -2.25%;
  max-width: 45vh;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
} /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-content p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vh;
}

.expertise-section-content button {
  font-size: 2vh;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #339a9a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* clear: both; May not need this included */
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.expertise-section-content button a {
  color: white;
}

.expertise-section-content button:hover {
  background-color: #004e4f;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
  ------------------------------------------------*/




@media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  } /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 6.5%;
  }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
  /*------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/

  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000;
  } /* Makes changes to sizing and positioning of the h1 tag */

  .expertise-section-title {
    margin-top: 0;
  } /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

  .expertise-section-title:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Creates horizontal line for the expertise section titles and sets positioning */

  .expertise-section-title span {
    background: #bce4b8;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    font-size: 26px;
    /* clear: both; May not need this included */
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
  }

  /*------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/
}
```

```html
<section id="expertise-section">
      <h1 class="expertise-section-title"><span>Why Choose Me?</span></h1>

    <div class="expertise-section-content">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="http://nathan-bayne.co.uk/images/pexels-anna-tarazevich-5910768.jpg" alt="image"/>
        <p>My approach is warm and understanding. I am here to listen to you and help you to make sense of difficult times.
        If you would like to find out more, you can read about my experience and qualifications by clicking the button below.
        </p>
        <button onclick="location.href='findoutmore.html'" type="button">Find Out More</button> <!-- Links to another page-->
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="location.href='findoutmore.html'" type="button">Find Out More</button>` this offends me in so many ways... Is there a reason this is just not an anchor, `a`, tag? Or at the very least just wrapped in an anchor tag

Comment: I created this part of the website about a month ago and remember having weird issues with it and this was a quick alternative. I'll be looking to tidy up the rest of the code towards the end of the project.

Comment: Just a friendly advice: generally, people hate to read long code. Try to reduce your examples by omitting any unrelated things. This is easier to read and this shows some respect to other people's time.

Comment: My bad. I thought everything I had within the code was relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these codes:

See: https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/bGBJpZW

```
.element {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:75%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
  .element {
    flex-wrap:wrap; // for mobile
  }
}
```

Apart from these, I made changes in HTML.

```css
#expertise-section {
  background-color: #bce4b8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0 0;
  min-height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
} /* Adjusts section sizing, padding and text alignment */


.element {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:75%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
  .element {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
------------------------------------------------*/

#expertise-section h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Lobster Two", cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -2%;
} /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-title {
  margin-top: 0;
} /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

.expertise-section-title span {
  background: #bce4b8;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
} /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

.expertise-section-content {
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-right: 14%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.expertise-section-content img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -2.25%;
  max-width: 45vh;
  max-height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  margin-right: 2em;
} /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

.expertise-section-content p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2vh;
}

.expertise-section-content button {
  font-size: 2vh;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #339a9a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* clear: both; May not need this included */
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.expertise-section-content button a {
  color: white;
}

.expertise-section-content button:hover {
  background-color: #004e4f;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

/*------------------------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION STYLING
  ------------------------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  } /* Sets colour, font, font size and position of the h1 title within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 6.5%;
  }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
  /*------------------------------
    START OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/

  #expertise-section h1 {
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000;
  } /* Makes changes to sizing and positioning of the h1 tag */

  .expertise-section-title {
    margin-top: 0;
  } /* Sets margin of the expertise title */

  .expertise-section-title span {
    background: #bce4b8;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  } /* Sets background of the expertise section background and sets padding for spacing between title and hr line */

  .expertise-section-content {
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
  }

  .expertise-section-content img {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
  } /* Sets size and positioning of image within the expertise section */

  .expertise-section-content p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .expertise-section-content button {
    font-size: 26px;
    /* clear: both; May not need this included */
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
  }

  /*------------------------------
    END OF EXPERTISE SECTION
  --------------------------------*/
}
```

```html
<section id="expertise-section">
      <h1 class="expertise-section-title"><span>Why Choose Me?</span></h1>

    <div class="expertise-section-content">
      <div class="element">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFokuIjWnHD5UGB2aJf5FzsLNmAdXCCYjeIw&usqp=CAU" alt="image"/>
        <p>My approach is warm and understanding. I am here to listen to you and help you to make sense of difficult times.
        If you would like to find out more, you can read about my experience and qualifications by clicking the button below.
        </p>
      </div>
              <button onclick="location.href='findoutmore.html'" type="button">Find Out More</button> <!-- Links to another page-->
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but it doesn't appear to be doing what I expected. The button isn't centred underneath the text properly, the text is still going really small when you adjust the height of the window, the image is going small, the content of the image and text is appearing in the upper section of the green section rather than in the middle (horizontally) when I adjust the height also.